# It is permitted to delete and upload again an application to Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app that in the beginning has some errors and a lot of users rate it with 1 star and now it have very bad rate.

Now the app has solved the errors but still have a lot of negative votes, and no one is downloading it because of the negative ratings.

It is allowed to delete the app and to upload it again to start with 0 installations and 0 rates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google requires each app to have a unique package name. Uploading it with the same package name will be a problem.

You can change the package name and keep all store information the same. Having the an app with an identical name as another app is acceptable (since you don't have trademark or copyright conflicts; you already use the existing name).

That should be sufficient to solve your problem. This is not a solution to re-publish an already banned app in order to avoid a Google policy problem. However, if your app is banned and you correct the issues, I have been advised by Google that it is acceptable to re-publish the same app with a different package name if you believe it to now be compliant.

They don't have a formal policy on re-publishing for cases specifically like yours. And I know it is possible because I have done it for reasons other than yours (I just wanted a new package name shortly after I published the original app).

Comment: ok, so it is legal then if i use another package name? i can not be banned?

Comment: No, it won't be banned. You might need to sign with a different key maybe.

Comment: sign it with a different key? why? the idea is to upload it in the same account with the same key, but with another package name, and to delete the old app

Comment: You may also want to edit your question - it is not really a legal issue, but a Google Play or Google policy issue